# Dynamic Fields with ManyToMany in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I want to define some fields for my model in another model. Here:

```
class Setting(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Option(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    setting = models.ForeignKey(Setting)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Car(models.Model):
    hsn = models.PositiveIntegerField("HSN", max_length=4)
    tsn = models.PositiveIntegerField("TSN", max_length=3)
    mileage = models.PositiveIntegerField("Kilometerstand")
    settings = models.ManyToManyField(Setting)
```

In the admin I want to have every Settings.name as a field in CarAdmin with a select box of Options.name

How can I do this?

Comment: create your own form for the modeladmin to use?

Answer (score 0):

I've run accross a similar problem and solved it as below, I believe it should do the trick.

What you want is to have the Settings as inlines in your Car changeform and a M2M field pointing toward Options in the Setting Inline, overriding its widget to display it as checkboxes.

In your models.py:

```
class Option(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Car(models.Model):
    hsn = models.PositiveIntegerField("HSN", max_length=4)
    tsn = models.PositiveIntegerField("TSN", max_length=3)
    mileage = models.PositiveIntegerField("Kilometerstand")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.hsn


class Setting(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    options = models.ManyToManyField(Option, blank=True, null=True)
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

In your admin.py :

```
from django.forms import CheckboxSelectMultiple

class OptionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Option, OptionAdmin)

class SettingInline(admin.TabularInline):

    model = Setting
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.ManyToManyField: {'widget': CheckboxSelectMultiple},
    }


class CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        SettingInline
    ]

admin.site.register(Car, CarAdmin)
```

There might be some caveats with this solution, such as common options for every setting or misplaced help text below checkboxes, I've not looked further but it should be fixable.